# Using induction on x to prove this inequality,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality

I want to show that

$$1 + \frac{2n}{1!} + \frac{(2n)^2}{2!} + ... + \frac{(2n)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \le  \frac{(2n)^n}{n!}   $$

in order to apply Rouche's Theorem inside the disk $|z|<2n$.

The solution gives a hint that says:

use induction to show that

$$1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{(x)^2}{2!} + ... + \frac{(x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \le  \frac{(x)^n}{n!}   $$

for all $x\ge 2n$.

I tried using the AM-GM inequality, but so far cannot simplify it enough to see whether it gives me the desired result.

Any hints are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not try one, and, if it doesn't work, try the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{HINT:}$ Assume 
$$1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{(x)^2}{2!} + ... + \frac{(x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \le  \frac{(x)^n}{n!}   $$
is true for $n$ when $x\ge2n$. Now add $\frac{(x)^n}{n!}$ on both sides and prove that 
$$2\frac{(x)^n}{n!}\le\frac{(x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$

Comment: but then i'd be assuming exactly what I am trying to prove, no? @mrprottolo,

Comment: No, that is the induction step: assuming is true for $n$ you prove that is true also for $n+1$.

Comment: adding that term on both sides does not produce a power of n+1, @mrprottolo, so there is no n+1 case to consider, it seems like,

Comment: I added a extra hint, try now if you can reach the solution.

Comment: Assume ... is true ** for some $n$**. Then the inductive argument shows it is true for $n+1$.

Comment: Ah, I got it now.  Nice second hint, very pretty.  But, it seems like we should prove a base case, no?

Comment: @user296906 Try $n = 1$

Comment: Hi @Thumbnail, the base case $n=1$ seems hard to prove...I am plugging in x=2 (since n=1) ...

Comment: @user296906 The case $n=1$ is $1\le x$ when $x\ge2\cdot 1$. That's not so hard.

Comment: @mrprottolo, isn't the n=1 case $(1+x)\le x$?  And that gives $3 \le 2$, which is absurd...

Comment: No, that's not case $n=1$, see my previous comment.

Comment: Seems like you're miscounting the n's on the L.H.S. n = 1 gives 1+x, doesn't it?  I could be wrong, though...but it seems like 1+x, @mrprottolo,

Comment: The base case doesn't work @mrprottolo ...

Comment: On the l.h.s. you have to sum up to $n-1$, so if $n=1$ you have just $1$.

Comment: OoooooOoo, rightttttt -- thanks for your patience @mrprottolo :-)

Comment: I just want lamb over rice, ice cream, and then go to bed, @mrprottolo :-(  thanks and have a great night :-)

Comment: @user296906 When $n = 1$, $n - 1 = 0$, so the condition is $1 \le x$ for $x \ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{(2n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = 2\frac{(2n+2)^n}{n!}\ge \frac{(2n+2)^n}{n!}+\frac{(2n+2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\dots+1
$$

Comment: Thanks Mr. Holden - have a great night, @DavidHolden :-)